# Populate select menus with data from Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to pass some values from database to populate a page with various select menus (around 5).

I can do this using `JSTL SQL` tag but it's not good practice.

How can I get this data from a single servlet?
Can I send multiple lists from one servlet?

The select menus are populated from different tables. I want to use `RequestDispatcher` to forward the lists to the jsp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use separate `ArrayList` to store the various lists retrieved in the Servlet and then store each list as a request attribute as mentioned by [@devsundar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471324/devsundar). You can retrieve these attributes in your JSP through the `request` implicit object.

And if you want to just send all the lists in a single request attribute then [@KaipaMSarma's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/713414/kaipa-m-sarma) suggestion is good to have a `HashMap<String, ArrayList>`, so your servlet code might look something like this:

```
List list1 = getListOneFromDatabase();
List list2 = getListTwoFromDatabase();
List list3 = getListThreeFromDatabase();
// and so on ...

Map<String, List> requestListMap = new HashMap<String, List>();
requestListMap.put("list1", list1);
requestListMap.put("list2", list2);
requestListMap.put("list3", list3);
// and so on ...

request.setAttribute("reqListMap", requestListMap);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the data from database in the request attribute and render it in your JSP.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)

Comment: True, but how can I put multiple lists into one request attribute? These lists will ideally come from different DAO's

Comment: okay.. i got your scenario. lets take a Arraylist/Map and put all your list inside it and set that object as an attribute

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do. From your servlet you can hit the Database(any number of tables) and store your result sets in collection object and pass those objects as attributes to JSP.